# Aqueous electrons in electrochemical cells

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electrochemistry

In the context of a zinc-copper electrochemical cell, zinc atoms at the anode are oxidized, releasing electrons and forming zinc ions that dissolve into the solution ($Zn(\text{s}) \rightarrow Zn^{2+}(\text{aq}) + 2e^-$). This process leaves electrons behind on the electrode. Given the high reactivity of electrons, it's intriguing that they don't also "dissolve" into the aqueous solution like the zinc ions. Considering the potential for radical formation if electrons were to interact with the solution, how is it that electrons are prevented from entering the solution? Is this just a case of textbooks leaving out a loose thread in the story of electrochemical cells?

As a side-note, I can imagine a metal plate under water onto which ultraviolet light is shone. I would guess that surface electrons could absorb the light and become free in the water. So I don't see why would a similar effect not sometimes occur from the bombardment of the electrode surfaces by molecules (rather than light) in the electrochemical solutions?